# How to add related table column in sql to_tsvector?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, search, tsvector

I am working on a django API in which I need to implement a search-as-you-type feature. At first I wanted to use Django SearchVector and SearchQuery but they seem to perform poorly when query terms are incomplete (which is not ideal for the "as-you-type" part) so I went for the SQL approach. I need to be able to search on first_name and last_name of a contact as well as on the email of the user related to that contact.

I used the following to create a search_vector on contact and to add an index on this column. This works great to search on first and last name.

```
ALTER TABLE contact_contact 
ADD COLUMN search_vector tsvector;
    
UPDATE contact_contact
SET search_vector = to_tsvector('english', coalesce(first_name, '') || ' ' || coalesce(last_name, ''));

CREATE INDEX mc_idx2 ON contact_contact USING GIN (search_vector);
```

I would like to add the user email to this `search_vector`, something like:

```
...
SET search_vector = to_tsvector('english', coalesce(first_name, '') || ' ' || coalesce(last_name, '') || coalesce(user.email::text, ' '));
...
```

I get the following error

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "." LINE 2: ...|| ' ' || coalesce(last_name, '') || coalesce(user.email::te..

The `"."` refers to `user.email
I cannot figure out the correct syntax or process to do that.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the error message  exactly

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "." LINE 2: ...|| ' ' || coalesce(last_name, '') || coalesce(user.email::te.. The "." refers to user.email

Comment: what is "user" is it the table name ? you are updating contact_contact

Comment: user is the name of the related table. I would like to update the `search_vector` column of the `contact_contact` table so that search can be performed on column `first_name` and `last_name` but also on `email`. `first_name` and `last_name` are columns from `contact_contact` table but `email` is a column from `user` table.

Comment: see my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

then you have to join between two tables:

```
UPDATE contact_contact cc
SET search_vector = to_tsvector('english', coalesce(first_name, '') || ' ' || coalesce(last_name, '') || ' ' || coalesce(u.email::text, '') || ' ' || coalesce(co.name::text, '')) 
FROM user u 
JOIN company co
 On co.contact_id = cc.id 
WHERE u.contact_id = cc.id
```

Comment: Thanks there was indeed a typo in my question! But that's not the reason this sql command is not working

Comment: Thank you so much that is exactly what I needed! Let's say I want to search on another related table company later. Would I get sth like this ?
`SET search_vector = to_tsvector('english', coalesce(first_name, '') || ' ' || coalesce(last_name, '') || ' ' || coalesce(u.email::text, '') || ' ' || coalesce(co.name::text, ''))
FROM user u, company co
WHERE u.contact_id = cc.id and co.contact_id = cc.id`

Comment: what is `company` in this case? I don't see the OP mentioning

Comment: @eLRuLL see their comment above